# Python is says my global name is not defined but it is defined?

Tags: python

```
def main():
  endProgram = 'no'
  print
  while endProgram == 'no':
    print


    pints = [0] * 7
    totalPints = 0
    averagePints = 0
    highPints = 0
    lowPints = 0

    pints = getPints(pints)
    totalPints = getTotal(pints, totalPints)
    averagePints = getAverage(totalPints, averagePints)
    highPints = getHigh(pints, highPints)
    lowPints = getLow(pints, lowPints)
    displayInfo(averagePints, highPints, lowPints)

    endProgram = raw_input('Do you want to end program? (yes or no): ')
    while not (endProgram == 'yes' or endProgram == 'no'):
        print 'Please enter a yes or no'
        endProgram = raw_input('Do you want to end program? (yes or no): ')

def getPints(pints):
    counter = 0
    while counter < 7:
        pints[counter] = input('Enter pints collected: ')
        counter = counter + 1
    return pints

def getTotal(pints, totalPints):
    counter = 0
    while counter < 7:
        totalPints = totalPints + pints[counter]
        counter = counter + 1
    return totalPints

def getAverage(totalPints, averagePints):
    averagePints = float(totalPints) / 7
    return averagePints

def getHigh(pins,highPints):
    highPints = pints[0]
    counter = 1
    while counter < 7:
        if pints[counter] > highPints:
            highPints = pints[counter]
        counter = counter + 1
    return highPints

def getLow(pints, lowPints):
    lowPints = pints[0]
    counter = 1
    while counter < 7:
        if pints[counter] < lowPints:
            lowPints = pints[counter]
            counter = counter + 1
    return lowPints

def displayInfo(averagePints, highPints, lowPints):
    print 'The average number of pints donated is', averagePints
    print 'The highest pints donated is', highPints
    print 'The lowest pints donated is', lowPints
print
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function `getHigh` you have the argument `pins` instead of `pints` and then your try to index `pints[0]`